# Compare 2-Tablix and Highlight Non-Duplicate Data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have an SSRS report with 2-tablix and would like to compare data and highlight rows that not non-duplicates. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks

[2-tablix for comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NMGw.png)

Answer (score 0):

In table2, for each of the cells you wish to highlight, use the following expression:
=IIF(len(Lookup(Fields!ClientID.Value,Fields!ClientID.Value, Fields!LastName.Value,"DataSet2"))>0,"Nothing","Yellow")